# ggplot plot, plotting by group across two variables

Tags: r

I have a data frame with a patient_name, treatment_status[positive, negative], values

```
variable = treatment_status
```

So its something like this should work -

```
ggplot(data = dat_m, aes(variable, value, group=factor(Patient_Name))) +
  geom_jitter(aes(color=factor(variable)))
```

But unfortunately my patient names don't show up across the x-axis. Is there any way to get this going. Much appreciate any help.

Comment: Difficult to answer without seeing some example data (`dat_m`), but it doesn't look like `patient_name` is the x-axis variable, so you would not expect to see it.

Comment: Could you provide a sample dataset to represent your data?

Comment: Need a reproducible example please!

Answer (score 4):

Sounds like you need a `interaction` function. Try this:

```
ggplot(data = dat_m, aes(x=interaction(Patient_Name,variable), value) +
  geom_jitter(aes(color=factor(variable)))
```